# SQL Select records excluding some statuses

Tags: sql, select

I'm totally stuck on how to create this select. I need to select from the status table only those `order_id`'s which to not have status 2.

Here is the table:

```
+----+---------+---------+--
| id | order_id| status  |
+----+---------+---------+--
|  1 |       1 |       1 | 
|  2 |       1 |       2 | 
|  3 |       2 |       1 | 
|  4 |       2 |       2 |
|  5 |       3 |       1 |
|  1 |       3 |       3 | 
|  2 |       4 |       2 | 
|  3 |       4 |       1 | 
|  4 |       4 |       2 |
|  5 |       5 |       3 | 
+----+---------+----------+--
```

So he select result will be only `order_id = 5`

Please help!

If you want to include orders with status 1 and exclude those with status 3, then you can use a similar idea:

```
having sum(case when status_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when status_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

EDIT: I like to EXCLUDE those order_id's:
 - Which has only status 1 (not status 2)
 - and
 - which has status 3

Lets have table like this:

```
id--order-id-Prod---Status    
------------------------------  

1   1        a      1  
6   1        b      2  
7   1        a      2  
8   1        b      1  
9   2        a      1  
10  3        a      1  
11  3        b      1  
12  3        a      2  
13  3        b      2  
14  4        a      1  
15  4        b      1  
16  5        a      1  
17  5        b      1  
18  5        a      2  
19  5        b      2  
20  5        a      3  
21  5        b      3
```

Select should show only order_id "5"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a set-within-sets query:

```
select order_id
from t
group by order_id
having sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows with a status of 2.  The `= 0` finds the orders with no matches.

EDIT:

If you want to include orders with status 1 and exclude those with status 3, then you can use a similar idea:

```
having sum(case when status_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when status_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: this works fine, however if I like to exclude those order_id's which has only status 1 and include order_id's which has status 3 (as earlier)... and table look like this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way.

```
Select * from TableName 
where Order_ID not in (Select order_ID from tableName where status=2)
```

Another way would be to use the not exists clause.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT order_id
FROM StatusTable

EXCEPT

SELECT order_id
FROM StatusTable
WHERE status = 2;
```

It works in SQL-Server and Postgres (and in Oracle if you replace the `EXCEPT` with `MINUS`.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this works, one query to select all ids, one to get those with a status of 2 and left joining on order_id and picking those with null order_id in the list of orders with a status of 2.

```
select 
  all_ids.order_id
from 
(
  select distinct
    order_id
  from status
) all_ids
left join
(
  select 
    order_id
  from status
  where status = 2
) two_ids
on all_ids.order_id = two_ids.order_id
where two_ids.order_id is null
```